# How to access base class method *args from child class object?

Tags: python, class, arguments

I am trying to get base class method `*args` from child class object. Here is the code:

```
class BaseView():

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)


class SecondLevelClass(BaseView):

    def print_kwargs(self):
        for key, value in self.__dict__.items():
            print(key, value)

        for x in self.args:
            print(x)

some_object = SecondLevelClass('something', name="John", second_name="Keller", age=23, 
                               location='France')

print(vars(some_object))
print(type(some_object))
print(some_object.print_kwargs())
```

The error message says: `AttributeError: 'SecondLevelClass' object has no attribute 'args'`

How do I get the `*args` that were passed to `__init__` if I want to print them?

UPDATE:
Updated the code with missing lines.

Comment: You can't. That was a local variable inside `BaseView.__init__` that you did nothing with. If you want that tuple to be accessible _outside_ that method, as you did with the content of `kwargs`, you need to assign it to an instance attribute (but then it'll also be in `self.__dict__`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe now I see what is the problem here. However, what is the practice to get access to the *args from the object of child class?

Comment: As I said, you'd need to assign it to an instance attribute. But the example here is so generic that it's more-or-less impossible to tell what you're actually trying to achieve. Also the indentation looks wrong in what you've posted - _test_ your examples before posting, make sure they actually recreate the issue.

Comment: It has nothing to do with children; the variable `args` is simply not stored anywhere and thus discarded after `__init__` is done. You need to store its value somewhere if you want to have access to it after `__init__` is done. Whether you do this inside the parent or child is just an additional but somewhat irrelevant detail. Start with defining where you'd want `arg` to be stored. On some instance attribute (`self...`)?

Comment: If you can't change `BaseView`, you are going to have to override `__init__` and *not* ignore the positional arguments passed to `SecondLevelClass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it to work if you save a copy of the attributes in the `__init__()` method of the derived class, so its `print_kwargs()` method can access them.

Here's what I mean:

```
class BaseView():

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)


class SecondLevelClass(BaseView):

    # ADDED
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def print_kwargs(self):
        for key, value in self.__dict__.items():
            print(key, value)

        for x in self.args:
            print(x)

some_object = SecondLevelClass('something', name="John", second_name="Keller", age=23,
                               location='France')

print(vars(some_object))
print(type(some_object))
print(some_object.print_kwargs())
```